# PIL processing - type error

Tags: python, types, python-imaging-library

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to get my head around the following in PIL. 
I was assuming that it was going to be straightforward but from the looks of it it ain't. 
So I'm loading an image, assigning pixel tuples to a list, and perform some elementary computations per pixel tuple (RGB). 
That much I have figured out. However, I would like to assign the resulting values to another list and trying to do that returns the following type error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

While I understand the mismatch, I don't really know how to solve it and correctly assign the resulting RGB values per pixel. I have the nasty feeling that this should be elementary.

Thank you in advance

```
i = Image.open("bike.jpg")
newpixels = []

pixels = i.load()
width, height = i.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        cpixel = pixels[x, y]
        rc = cpixel[0]
        gc = cpixel[1]
        bc = cpixel[2]

        if rc < 128:
            newR = 0
        else:
            newR = 1

        if gc < 128:
            newG = 0
        else:
            newG = 1


        if bc < 128:
            newB = 0
        else:
            newB = 1

        newpixels[x,y] = (newR, newG, newB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python lists don't work like that. There's no such thing as a two-dimensional list in that way: instead, you use a list of lists. So you need to build up your new version row by row.

```
newpixels = []
for x in range(width):
    newrow = []
    for y in range(height):
        ... code here ...
        newrow.append((newR, newG, newB))
    newpixels.append(newrow)
```

Comment: Interesting! Looks like I have to follow the inverse path of decomposing the image into pixel tuples. I'll give it a go and see if I can get it to work. Many thanx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `[x, y]` indexing for `newpixel`, which is defined as a regular python list:

```
newpixels = []
```

Python lists can be indexed only with a single integer value (like `newpixels[idx]`). **PIL**'s pixel-data object allows indexing using `[x, y]` notation, but it's not regular python `list`.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but if what you want is to create new Image, just create a blank image with the correct size and change it's pixel data:

so change:

```
newpixels = []
```

to

```
new_img = Image.new('RGB', i.size)
newpixels = new_img.load()
```

And then the result of your image processing will be in `new_img`.

Comment: Thanx for your explanation re PIL objects. I just trying to find my way around PIL so I can confidently read the RGB values per pixel, do some computations, and then replace the new values per pixel onto the old ones.